# Update URL when using Ajax call in MVC 4

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using Ajax Begin for in my view to make an asynchronous call to filter some results on my view. I have it working fine but the url does not get updated with the search filter like it did when I was doing a full page refresh.

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm(new AjaxOptions
{
    HttpMethod = "get",
    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
    UpdateTargetId = "LegislatorList",
    OnSuccess = "changeUrl(data)"
}))
{
    <input type="submit" name="chamber" value="House" />
    <input type="submit" name="chamber" value="Senate" />
    <input type="submit" name="chamber" value="Other" />
    <input type="submit" name="chamber" value="All" />
}
```

I tried using the onsuccess property to create the new url but it was not working properly.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Modify the URL without reloading the page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/824349/modify-the-url-without-reloading-the-page)

Comment: What is `changeUrl()` doing?